# Why ī is the only romaji that can be spelled as a double ii

Tags: kana, kana-usage

I am learning Japanese, and need to enter romaji into my keyboard to enter Japanese into documents and tables on my smartphone.

My textbook shows ī as the only romaji that can be spelled as a double ii.

[image: romahi long vowels]

Is this a commonplace romaji writing convention, and if so, then why is this?

EDIT:

Would I be right in saying that it is because the alphabetical combinations いい occur in Japanese (words), whereas ああ, うう, ええ, おお do not?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was mostly just extrapolation and should not be taken as facts in anyway. Is your purpose for learning romaji only to write kana into your PC/smartphone with something like microsoft ime?

Comment: Well, to be honest I also want to know why the author of my book choose this representational choice (without asking then directly). Thanks.

Comment: Although still a guess, I would say that considering romaji is supposed to help English(?) speakers write in a way that sounds like Japanese that perhaps ii the the only one that stays similar to the Japanese pronunciation. For example, English speakers would pronounce "ee" as "i" and not a long "e" sound.

Comment: although quite rare, I'm pretty sure some kanji can be read "おお" or "ええ" or "ああ". Probably not "うう"

Comment: While some kanji can have kana spellings like おお or ええ, the romaji would be *ō* or *ē*.  As to why いい gets special treatment, I believe this comes down to one key issue -- romaji spellings "split" at morpheme (broadly, grammatical unit of meaning) boundaries.  If the long *i* sound is part of a single morpheme, as in お兄{にい}さん, the romanization would use *ī*, as in *onīsan*.  However, if the long *i* sound straddles a morpheme boundary, as in いい, the romanization would use *ii*.

Comment: More specifically, the second part of the long *i* in いい belongs to a different grammatical component -- the second い is the adjective ending, and this part can change.  The adjective いい might not be the best example, since the adverbial form is よく and not いく.  A better example might be いいます.  In plain form, this is いう.  We see that the second い in いいます is part of the verb ending that conjugates -- only the first い stays the same.  From what I've read, this was part of the logic for why いい is sometimes romanized as *ii*.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi comments are not for answers ;)

Comment: @永劫回帰 Derp. :) I started just replying to stack reader and got carried away. I'm crashing now; I may move my comment to an answer later if no one has beat me to it.

Comment: In the first place, that text book is wrong in the point that it fails to refer to おう which is pronounced as /ou/ instead of the long vowel and the katakana counterparts エイ and オウ.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, apparently some Japanese users make theオウ versus オオ distinction, while others do not. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hepburn originally transcribed `いい` as `ī`, but in later editions he changed it to `ii`.  Unfortunately, his book doesn't explain why he made this decision, so I can't say with certainty what the reason was.

I think one reason is most obvious and likely, however: `ī` looks very similar to `i`, and writing `ii` avoids confusing the two.  This isn't a problem for `a`, `u`, `e`, or `o` because they don't normally have dots over them, so they're visually distinct from `ā`, `ū`, `ē`, `ō`.

Note that Hepburn did not make the distinction mentioned in Eiríkr Útlendi's comment; he transcribed `いい` in all cases as `ii`.  Although a few people do make that distinction, it's not common to do so, and you don't have to worry about it as a learner.

You wrote:

> Would I be right in saying that it is because the alphabetical combinations いい occur in Japanese (words), whereas ああ, うう, ええ, おお do not?

No.  We can find all five kana sequences in Japanese words.  The easiest examples for the rest are interjections: `ああ`, `ううん`, `ええ`, and `おお`.  Interjections aside, `ああ` is also an adverb, and `おお` appears in a number of words such as `おおい` and `おおげさ`.  We can find more examples if we include sequences that cross morpheme boundaries, such as `ええん` (会厭) and `ふうう` (風雨).

If you intended to include examples where a long vowel follows a consonant (although these are technically excluded by what you wrote), we can find more examples rather easily: `おかあさん`, `ずうずうしい`, `おねえさん`, and `ほのお`.

The explanation in your edit doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and addresses and answers all of my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are several kinds of romanizations, each with its own set of rules.
Those rules were decided by whoever designed that romanization.
So if you ask the reasons for a certain romanization... who knows? Probably only the creator of that romanization knows the reason.

But I have a guess: I think ii is listed just because i and ī are too similar and difficult to tell apart.
So in order to avoid confusion they may use ii instead of ī.

Answer (score 1):

( Maybe someone said this in the comment already. )

I think it's because (the long vowel) いい appears in regular words, as -- かわいい、いいこと、いいます、（人名、地名：　いいだ） . . .

( So if you romanize these, they'd be: kawaii, iikoto, iimasu, iida, ... )

Whereas ああ, うう, ええ, おお usually do not.  Instead, they are usually written with the bar (?)  "ー"　（長音記号） sign :

- アーサー、ツアー、アームストロング、（嗚呼） 『あゝ玉杯に花うけて』
- ウーロン茶、ウーパールーパー
- エールフランス、エーデルワイス　-- Exceptions where ええ is used : 「ええ話や…」
- オープン、オーストリア、オート三輪

おお is used : 　おおかみ、オオカミ、オオクワガタ、…　　おおきな、おおらかな、おおしい、（人名、地名：　おおき, etc.）

But "ee" and "oo" are avoided because they may be confusing : "feet" and "food", etc.

Answer (score -3):

the double ii was copied form european laguages ( romanian an italian).. as this did not exist in Japanese languages before 19 century and japan look towards europe for inspiration. It could also be that japan has strong feelings towards(hawaii)